# converting Java Script to PowerShell

Tags: javascript, powershell, encoding, decoding

I am trying to translate the following to PowerShell to include in a PowerShell script that will make an API call.  The API use JWT signing.  The following is from a pre-request script the vendor is using in Postman.  Everything works perfect in Postman.  If I use the JWT created by the pre-request script in my PowerShell script it works.  The problem is with the JWT signing section of my PowerShell code.

```
 // Create JWT
 var unsignedRequest = base64object(jwtHeader) + "." + base64object(jwtPayload);

 // Decode the use_base64_key
 var key = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(pm.variables.get("use_base64_key"));

 // Sign the JWT  
 var signatureHash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(unsignedRequest, key);
 var signature = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(signatureHash);
 var signature = removeIllegalCharacters(signature);
```

I've tried using some samples from JWT.io.  I think my specific issue is not being able to replicate this section.

```
 Decode the use_base64_key
 var key = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(pm.variables.get("use_base64_key"));
```

The key we are provided is base64 and according to the vendor it has to be decoded first.  As I understand the above section, this decodes the base64 to a wordarray.  This is part I think PS script is missing.

Edit to add code suggested by boxdog-
The error I get from the request is 403 forbidden.  Meaning the request could not be verified.

```
# VARIABLES
$Algorithm="HS256"
$ContentType="application/json"
$SecretKey=""
$use_base64_key=""
$org_alias=""

# PRE-REQ
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Security

# FUNCTIONS
Function Get-HMACSHA512 {
    param(
         [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$data
        ,[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$key
    )
    $hmacsha = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256  
    $hmacsha.key = [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($key)
    $bytesToSign = [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($data)
    $sign = $hmacsha.ComputeHash($bytesToSign)
    return $sign
}

Function Get-StringFromByte {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][byte[]]$byteArray
    )
    $stringBuilder = ""
    $byteArray | ForEach { $stringBuilder += $_.ToString("x2") }
    return $stringBuilder
}

Function Get-Base64UrlEncodeFromString {
    param(
         [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$inputString
    )
    $inputBytes = [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($inputString)
    # Special "url-safe" base64 encode.
    $base64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($inputBytes,[Base64FormattingOptions]::None).Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_').Replace("=", "")
    return $base64
}

Function Get-Base64UrlEncodeFromByteArray {
    param(
         [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][byte[]]$byteArray
    )
    # Special "url-safe" base64 encode.
    $base64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($byteArray,[Base64FormattingOptions]::None).Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_').Replace("=", "")
    return $base64
}

Function Get-Base64FromString {
    param(
         [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$inputString
    )
    $inputBytes = [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($inputString)
    # Special "url-safe" base64 encode.
    $base64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($inputBytes,[Base64FormattingOptions]::None)
    return $base64
}

Function Get-Base64FromByteArray {
    param(
         [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][byte[]]$byteArray
    )
    $base64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($byteArray,[Base64FormattingOptions]::None)
    return $base64
}

Function Check-Base64 {
# Add missing "=" at the end and check url-safe encodings
    param(
         [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$inputString
    )
    #$input
    $encoded = $inputString.Replace('-','+').Replace('_','/')
    $d = $encoded.Length % 4
    if ( $d -ne 0 ) {
        $encoded  = $encoded.TrimEnd('=')
        if ( $d % 2 -gt 0 ) {
            $encoded += '='
        } else {
            $encoded += '=='
        }
    }
    return $encoded
}

Function Create-JWT {
    param(
          [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary]$headers
         ,[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary]$payload
         ,[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$secret
    )
    $headersJson = $headers | ConvertTo-Json
    $payloadJson = $payload | ConvertTo-Json
    $headersEncoded = Get-Base64UrlEncodeFromString -inputString $headersJson #[System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($headersJson),[Base64FormattingOptions]::None)
    $payloadEncoded = Get-Base64UrlEncodeFromString -inputString $payloadJson #[System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($payloadJson),[Base64FormattingOptions]::None)
    $content = "$( $headersEncoded ).$( $payloadEncoded )"
    $signatureByte = Get-HMACSHA512 -data $content -key $secret
    $signature = Get-Base64UrlEncodeFromByteArray -byteArray $signatureByte
    $jwt = "$( $headersEncoded ).$( $payloadEncoded ).$( $signature )"
    return $jwt
}

# MAIN CODE
# Get Username to verify
$username = read-host "Enter username in UPN format (i.e. SmithJ@google.com) -->"

#Get-user API call

#Header
$headers=[ordered]@{alg=$Algorithm; org_alias= $org_alias; token=$SecretKey}

#Payload
$payload=[ordered]@{reqHeader = [ordered]@{
  locale='en'; 
  orgAlias=$org_alias;
  secretKey=$SecretKey;
  timestamp=((get-date).ToUniversalTime());
  version='4.9'}
  reqBody = [ordered]@{
  getSameDeviceUsers = "true";
  userName = $username
    }
 }


# Create JWT
$secret = $secretkey
$jwt = Create-JWT -headers $headers -payload $payload -secret $use_base64_key


#sending request
$RESTheader = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$RESTheader.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
$apiresponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://idpxnyl3m.pingidentity.com/pingid/rest/4/getuserdetails/do' -Method 'POST' -Headers $RESTheader -Body $JWT
```

Comment: You really should post your code and any error messages.  _"I've written something that doesn't work (that I'm keeping secret), now you have a go..."_ isn't really how SO works.  You should show what you've done and give as precise details as possible of where and how it fails.

Comment: Powershell is written in c# so when you have issues always look at the c# solutions.   See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha256?view=net-7.0

Comment: It is pretty hard to follow your question. Pair it down and ask a more focused question. Also it is very common for API to base64 encode.